# Frequency table with R (from raw time series)

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have a `.csv` file with a time series.
I am trying to use `ts()`, and to plot it! But my initial dataset is one row for one action. So I want to do a table, with the frequencies.
I've done that, but for the (existing) days I don't have data for, I'd like to assign a 0 frequency value!

Here is a sample of my data :

```
> table(ech$Date.Time) # Frequencies of observed dates
```

[image: table : frequencies of observed dates]

I generated all existing dates, using :

```
> seq.Date(from = min(ech$Date.Time), to = max(ech$Date.Time), by = 1)
```

And here is the result I'd like to get :

[image: result wanted]

I tried several things, but it is not working the way I'd like to!
Here is an example of what I tried, but it is not printing anything, and I don't understand the error message.

```
> plot(ts(data = ech, deltat = table(ech$Date.Time)))
```

`Error in plot(ts(data = ech, deltat = ech$Date.Time)) : 
  erreur d'évaluation de l'argument 'x' lors de la sélection d'une méthode pour la fonction 'plot' : Error in Ops.Date(1, deltat) : / not defined for "Date" objects`

Should I use `deltat`, or `frequency`, or something else prior to use `ts()` ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `merge` to combine the full sequence of dates to your data set.

You need to make sure the dates columns are of the same class (Date on this occasion).

Using your data set and the sequence of dates:

```
#sequence of dates
dates2 <- data.frame(dates = seq(as.Date('2014-04-05'), as.Date('2014-04-15'), by = 1))

#merging the ech to sequence of dates
newdf <- merge(dates2, ech, all.x = TRUE, by = 'dates')
#setting NA to zero
newdf$freq[is.na(newdf$freq)] <- 0
```

Output:

```
        dates freq
1  2014-04-05    1
2  2014-04-06    1
3  2014-04-07    2
4  2014-04-08    0
5  2014-04-09    0
6  2014-04-10    2
7  2014-04-11    0
8  2014-04-12    1
9  2014-04-13    0
10 2014-04-14    2
11 2014-04-15    1
```

For completion I used this as ech:

```
dates <- as.Date(c("2014-04-05", "2014-04-06", "2014-04-07", 
                   "2014-04-10", "2014-04-12", "2014-04-14", "2014-04-15"))
freq <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1)
ech <- data.frame(dates, freq)
```

Comment: That's perfect, I didn't know about this merge function ...
Thank you very much for your help !